# Source for a rabbi warning his student/son?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli

I distinctly remember a passage in the Talmud that went something like this: A Rav advises his student (or son) that he should ensure that he uses the correct Torah scroll or chumash when praying/studying as there were false (or inaccurate) copies in circulation.

Does anyone know the tractate for the above paraphrased passage?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked but quasi relevant is [Kesubos 19b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.19b.4)